# Partial derivative of complex function formula

Tags: complex-numbers

The question is "Prove the equivalence of the operators $\frac{\partial}{\partial{x}}=\frac{\partial}{\partial{z}}+\frac{\partial}{\partial{\bar{z}}}$"

The solution in the book then goes on to say "if $F$ is any continuously differentiable function, then

$\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{y}}=\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{z}}\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{x}}+\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{\bar{z}}}\frac{\partial{\bar{z}}}{\partial{x}}=\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{z}}+\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{\bar{z}}}$

I don't know where this formula came from. It looks like some application of the chain rule. Some help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Are you asking about Wirtinger derivatives?

Comment: I'm asking about partial derivatives of complex functions. What are Wirtinger derivatives?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_derivatives#Functions_of_one_complex_variable

Comment: Yes I am asking why they are true

Comment: Apply them to a function $f$ and show that the right and left hand sides are the same.

Comment: Yes, it's the chain rule. You can view $F$ as either a function of $z$ and $\bar z$ or as a function of $x$ and $y$ via $F(z(x,y), \bar z(x,y))$ where $z(x,y) = x+iy$ and $\bar z(x,y) = x-iy$.